# Capacitor Local Notification in Android not showing attachment image

Tags: ionic-framework

Local Notification not showing Attachment image in Android but the same code working fine in iOS.

Moreover I have seen in youtube videos attachment is not working for other developers as well.Any solution for this

```
I am using below Link :- 
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reaching me out,  I am using below plugin https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications      and the whole code is from above link only